# how to regex replace before colon?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

this is my original string:

```
NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1
```

I want to only add back slash to all the spaces before ':'

so, this is what I finally want:

```
NetworkManager/system\ connections/Wired\ 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1
```

I need to do this in bash, so, sed, awk, grep are all ok for me.

I have tried following sed, but none of them work

```
echo NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1 | sed 's/ .*\(:.*$\)/\\ .*\1/g'
echo NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1 | sed 's/\( \).*\(:.*$\)/\\ \1.*\2/g'
echo NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1 | sed 's/ .*\(:.*$\)/\\ \1/g'
echo NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1 | sed 's/\( \).*\(:.*$\)/\\ \1\2/g'
```

thanks for answering my question.
I am still quite newbie to stackoverflow, I don't know how to control the format in comment.
so, I just edit my original question

my real story is:

when I do grep or use cscope to search keyword, for example "address1" under /etc folder.
the result would be like:

```
./NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1
```

if I use vim to open file under cursor, suppose my vim cursor is now at word "NetworkManager",
then vim will understand it as

"./NetworkManager/system"

that's why I want to add "\" before space, so the search result would be more vim friendly:)

I did try to change cscope's source code, but very difficult to fully achieve this. so have to do a post replacement:(

Comment: If you can use a platform such as Perl that supports `\K` (reset the start of the match and discard all previously-matched characters) and `\G` (sets the position at the end of the previous match or at the start of the string before the first match is made), you can perform substitutions with the following regular expression: `^[^:]*?\K |\G[^:]*?\K `. (There is a space after each `\K`.) [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Y47vM/1). Hover the cursor over each element of the regular expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're trying to solve a spaces-in-the-input problem by escaping them rather than quoting your string, especially given the `echo` in your question that's missing quotes. What are you doing with those strings that makes you think you need to add backslashes before the spaces?

Comment: @EdMorton 
thanks for asking.
my real story is:
when I do grep or use cscope to search keyword "address1" under /etc folder.
the result would be like:


    ./NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1


if I use vim to open file under cursor, suppose my vim cursor is now at word "NetworkManager",
then vim will understand it as 


"./NetworkManager/system"


that's why I want to add "\" before space, so the search result would be more vim friendly:)

Comment: As someone who used `grep` and `cscope` almost daily for about 30 years, I've never encountered that problem. I have always used `vi` instead of `vim` and I've never tried opening a file from inside `vi` though. Based on questions we see here it seems like a lot of people use `vim` for things a shell is better suited for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to do the replacements if there is a `:` present in the string, you can check if there are at least 2 columns, setting the (output)field separator to a colon.

Data:

```
cat file                                                                                                                                       michaelvandam@Michaels-MacBook-Pro
NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1
NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection 14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1%
```

Example in `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"}{if(NF>1)gsub(" ","\\ ",$1)}1' file
```

Output

```
NetworkManager/system\ connections/Wired\ 1.nmconnection:14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1
NetworkManager/system connections/Wired 1.nmconnection 14 address1=10.1.10.71/24,10.1.10.1
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be simply done in `awk` program, with your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {gsub(/ /,"\\\\&",$1)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator and output field separator as `:` for this program. Then in main program using `gsub`(Global substitution) function of `awk`. Where substituting space with `\`  in 1st field only(as per OP's remarks it should be done before `:`) and printing line then.

Answer (score 3):

An idea for a [perl one liner](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-perl-one-liners.html) in bash to use [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and [`\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) (similar [@CarySwoveland's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70444758/how-to-regex-replace-before-colon#comment124526940_70444758)).

```
perl -pe 's/\G[^ :]*\K /\\ /g' myfile
```

[See this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##RcixCsIwEIDhV7ktIJrzpCAUnB1EVwejEJOjLbVJuQuI4LtHF3H54fvvXvtaOfQZzInLM8t49Ml3LKgvLTxByClxKENOiudBOALZNP1vSw34GIVVaUdrS/abLeGmWf5EBt4wszxgNTMYRbe/3KC9LtwB0DnAztT6AQ) or a [pattern demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/L3ozMV/1).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -E ':a;s/^([^: ]*) /\1\n/;ta;s/\n/\\ /g' file
```

Replace spaces before `:` by newlines then replace newlines by `\` 's.

Alternative using the hold space:

```
 sed -E 's/:/\n:/;h;s/ /\\ /g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Split the line on the first `:`.

Amend the front section, remove the middle and append the unadulterated back section.

Comment: the first one doesn't work in macos, the second one works.

Comment: @huangyingw are you saying the first GNU sed solution does not work in macos?

Comment: correct, the first one doesn't work in macos

Answer (score 0):

My answer is ugly and I think [RavinderSingh13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444917/11261546) is THE ONE, but I already took the time to write mine and it works (It's written step by step, but it's a one line command):

I got inspired by [HatLess answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70445805/11261546):

first get the text before the `:` with `cut` (I put the string in a file to make it easy to read, but this works on `echo`):

```
cut -d':' -f1 infile
```

Then replace spaces using `sed`:

```
cut -d':' -f1 infile | sed 's/\([a-z]\) /\1\\ /g'
```

Then `echo` the output with no new line:

```
echo -n "$(cut -d':' -f1 infile | sed -e 's/\([a-z]\) /\1\\ /g')"
```

Add the missing `:` and what comes after it:

```
echo -n "$(cut -d':' -f1 infile | sed -e 's/\([a-z]\) /\1\\ /g')" | cat - <(echo -n :) | cat - <(cut -d':' -f2 infile)
```